# Optimize a Double groupby performance

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

So I have a dataframe which would look like:

```
index first_key second_key data text  other
  1      34        987       2   'a'  'name'
  2      34        987       3   'b'  'name' 
  3      40        340       2   'c'  'dog'
  4      34        123       23  'd'  'name'
```

it is pulled from a database using a `JOIN`
and I want an array which would look like:

```
[
   {
     first_key: 34,
     other: 'name',
     second_key: [
        {
          second_key: 987,
          data: [2, 3],
          text: ['a', 'b']
        },
        {
          second_key: 123,
          data: [2],
          text: ['c']
        }
     ]
   }
   {
     first_key: 40,
     other: 'dog',
     second_key: [
        {
          second_key: 340,
          data: [2, 3],
          text: ['a', 'b']
        }
     ]
   }
]
```

Right now, I am just looping through each row and building the output piece by piece but it is really slow. Would be much faster to collapse those row first.

I tried with `groupby` and `groups` and `numpy` but I cant make it happens. Performance is critical here.

Thank you !

Comment: You can use pandas.DataFrame.to_json with orient='records' [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: That doesnt group the fields.

Comment: You should group your dataframe first

Comment: `df.groupby(['first_key', 'second_key']).apply(dict)` kinda works

Comment: good if you find the solution.

Comment: it doesnt exactly work tho... its getting closer.

Comment: Can you show me the result after my solution.

Comment: Your solution doesnt work @FadySaad . it just flatten out the thing.

Comment: it gives something like `[ {'first key': 34, ... } , { ... } , {...} ] ` for each row.

Answer (score 0):

This comes quite close:

```
new_index = ['first_key', 'other', 'second_key']
df2 = df.set_index(new_index).groupby(new_index).apply(dict)
foo = json.loads(df2.to_json(orient='table'))
print json.dumps(foo, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: I dont see any difference for having `set_index` or not. what does it change ?

Comment: If you omit `set_index(['first_key', 'other', 'second_key'])`, the values for 'first_key', 'other' and 'second_key' will be repeated inside the dictionary.